# How to get permalink in foreach loop

Tags: permalinks

What to do in situation when I don't have an ordinary if-while loop, how do I get permalink?

```
$page_children = get_page_children( 8, $all_wp_pages );

foreach( $page_children as $page ) :

    echo $page->post_title;
    the_permalink();

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) function and pass $page as an argument.

```
foreach( $page_children as $page ) :

  echo $page->post_title;
  get_permalink($page);

endforeach;
```